# A standard way/approach to handle questions that are better for other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

There is a tendency, i.e. in recent posts, to group almost every conceivable line of enquiry under History (because the subject is so broad). One could say, OP has no clear idea where to start and using the question as *a form of discovery*.

***If we begin to discover*** it is not suitable for history, and perhaps better served in Law (say) -- what is the SOP to 'push' it there? If there's no standard approach, is it a good idea to develop one?

Comment: I think we already close too many questions for being "off-topic". I asked a [question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3496/24858) here on Meta about questions on the history of politics. The response didn't exactly set the world alight!

Comment: Fair enough. I don't follow meta enough to get the pulse. Thanks.

Comment: I don't want History SE to become "Stack Overflow" for questions that belong elsewhere. So I would flag for migration any question that has a great "percentage" of another topic than History.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is to flag the question, request moderator intervention to migrate to the new site.

That said, I think we commonly try to assist OP to clarify the question before migration.